# Android Studio shortcuts for navigating inside a file?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

What are the shortcuts for navigating inside a class/file in Android Studio?

I know about `Shift+Ctrl+Up/Down` which only navigates between global properties and method declarations defined in a class. It doesn't allow me to navigate inside the content of a method for example.

I also know about `Command+Shift+[` and `Command+Shift+]` to move to the start of a code block and to the end of a code block.

What are my other options to navigate with shortcuts within a file aside from the aforementioned ones? Is there something equivalent to `Option+Up/Down` in  internet browsers for quick scrolling?

I'm on Mac but if you're on Windows feel free to answer too, I can figure out what the corresponding keys would be on Mac.

Comment: See the "Editor Actions" group in Keymap settings: https://i.imgur.com/JaEMHov.png

Comment: @Konstantin Annikov Thanks :) I have set `Move Caret Forward a Paragraph` and `Move Caret Backward a Paragraph` actions to  `fn+option+up/down` now. Works great.

Comment: If the answer was useful, please mark it as accepted. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the actions listed in the "Editor Actions" group of Keymap settings:
[image]